# Pandas+Uncertainties producing AttributeError: type object 'dtype' has no attribute 'kind'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, uncertainty

I want to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) + [Uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/). I am getting a strange error, below a MWE:

```py
from uncertainties import ufloat
import pandas

number_with_uncertainty = ufloat(2,1)

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [number_with_uncertainty]}) # This line works fine.

df.loc[0,'b'] = ufloat(3,1) # This line fails.
```

I have noticed that if I try to add the `ufloat`s "on the fly", as I usually do with a `float` or some other stuff, it fails. If I first create a `Series` then it works:

```py
from uncertainties import ufloat
import pandas

number_with_uncertainty = ufloat(2,1)

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [number_with_uncertainty]}) # This line works fine.

df['b'] = pandas.Series([ufloat(3,1)]) # Now it works.

print(df)
```

This makes it more cumbersome when calculating values on the fly within a loop as I have to create a temporary `Series` and after the loop add it as a column into my data frame.

Is this a problem of Pandas, a problem of Uncertainties, or am I doing something that is not supposed to be done?

Comment: I just hit this myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because when pandas tries to create a new column it checks the `dtype` of the new value so that it knows what `dtype` to assign to that column. For some reason, the `dtype` check on the `ufloat` value fails. I believe this is a bug that will have to be fixed in uncertainties.

A workaround in the interim is to manually create the new column with `dtype` set to `object`, for example in your case above:

```py
from uncertainties import ufloat
import pandas
import numpy

number_with_uncertainty = ufloat(2,1)

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [number_with_uncertainty]}) # This line works fine.

# create a new column with the correct dtype
df.loc[:, 'b'] = numpy.zeros(len(df), dtype=object)

df.loc[0,'b'] = ufloat(3,1) # This line now works.
```